# PHP version of ASP.NET/C# property attribute class

Tags: c#, php, attributes, properties

Is there such a thing?

I'd like to do something like this in PHP but I can't see how to do it from the PHP docs:

```
public class User : ValidationBase
{  
  [NotNullOrEmpty(Message = "Please enter a user name.")] 
  public string UserName { get; set; } 
}
```

What I'm looking for is the PHP equivalent of an ASP.NET/C# property attribute, which in the above example is signified by the `[NotNullOrEmpty(Message = "Please enter a user name.")]` line above the property declaration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP has no built-in mechanism for declaring attributes, but it is possible to simulate this behavior using some custom code. The basic idea is to place your metadata in a comment block, and then write a class that parses that comment block. This is less convenient than C# because you need to ensure that your comment "attributes" are formatted properly, but it works.

Here is an example of how to do this: http://web.archive.org/web/20130302084638/http://interfacelab.com/metadataattributes-in-php/

Comment: This looks like it's the closest to what I'm looking for. Thanks so much, Andy.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer from Andy Wilson links to pages which are no longer available. I managed to get to the page itself through http://web.archive.org/web/20130116184636/http://interfacelab.com/metadataattributes-in-php/ but the code download the author refers to is a dead link too.

However I've since found a great implementation of PHP Annotations here: https://github.com/mindplay-dk/php-annotations

The only downside I've found so far is that is relies on your file names and class names being the same and of the **same case** which with Code Igniter they aren't but once I'd worked this out I soon had it all working and of course this limitation wouldn't affect all implementations.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not, at least not natively supported by PHP.

You can use a framework that will provide with validation for forms, for instance. The [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) has a [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html#zend.form.quickstart.elements) class that allow to specify if fields are required, what type they should be, and the error message to display if it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in PHP, you'll actually have to code it.

A bit like this, I suppose :

```
public function setUserName($str) {
    if (empty($str)) {
        throw new Exception('Please enter a user name.');
    }
    $this->userName = $str;
}

public function getUserName($str) {
    return $this->userName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some frameworks can bring this kind of functionality, but PHP is not designed to provide such high-level constructs.

Answer (score 0):

php does not have properties nor property attributes.

if you'd like to do something similar in php, you'd have to declare a private field, and write public getter and setter methods, and do some sort of null checking within the setter method.

```
class User extends ValidationBase
{
    private $userName;
    public function GetUserName()
    {
        return $this->userName;
    }
    public function SetUserName($val = '')
    {
        if ($val === '')
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->userName = $val;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mentioned, with PHP below 5.0 it wasn't possible, however since PHP 5.0 [it is possible](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php) to mimic C# functionality using `DocComment`

I took the idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571602) and modified it for purpose of this question. It is possible to use a `JSON` string as `DocComment` to make it easier to parse later and access them using reflection from your code as below

```
<?php
/** {"Description":"This is a test class"} */
class User {

   /** {"Message":"Please enter a user name."} */
   public $Username;

   /** {"Message":"Please enter a user name."} */
   public function Login($username) {
        print "Inside `aMemberFunc()`";
    }
}

$rc = new ReflectionClass("User");  // class name
print $rc->getDocComment()                          . "<br />\n"; // Get Class comment
print $rc->getMethod("Login")->getDocComment()      . "<br />\n"; // Get Method comment
print $rc->getProperty("Username")->getDocComment() . "<br />\n"; // Get Property comment

?>
```

With following results

```
/** {"Description":"This is a test class"} */
/** {"Message":"Please enter a user name."} */
/** {"Message":"Please enter a user name."} */
```

Going further from here should be easy, remove `DocComment` markers and parse it as JSON to have an object with your properties. There are more `reflection` methods available such as getting list of properties, methods and constants, which you can read about it at [PHP reflection manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

**Note:** Compiling with `Zend` and such, will remove comments from your code and they will not be available, thus you will need to configure your platform to leave comments alone.

Answer (score 0):

I used doc comments in reflection. See more info [ReflectionClass::getDocComment](https://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php)

Here is example code [from my project](https://github.com/fatihbahceci/php-mvp)

```
/**
* You can use doc comments in reflection. 
* See more info https://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php
* 
* @role("admin")
*/
class permissiontest extends Page
{
    public function render($p)
    {
        echo 'Howdy friend!';
        //$this->renderView($p);
    }
}
```

Reflection

```
class handler 
{
    public function OnPageRendering($page)
    {
        $r = new ReflectionClass(get_class($page));
        $s = $r->getDocComment();
        if (!str::isNullOrEmpty(trim($s))) {
            // tags::pre($s);
            /**
             * @role("filter")
             */
            $matches = array();
            //@role("filter") https://regex101.com/
            preg_match('/@role\(\"(.*)\"\)/', $s, $matches);
            if (!arrays::isNullOrEmpty($matches)) {
            // tags::pre($matches);//Array ( [0] => @role("filter") [1] => filter ) 
            // tags::pre($matches[0]);//@role("filter")        
            // tags::pre($matches[1]);//filter
                $filter = $matches[1];
                //tags::h("Check Permission for:".$filter);
                if (!userHasRights($filter)) {
                    die('You do not have permission on this page! Process stopped!');
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
function userHasRights($right) {
    return false;
}
```