# PHP - Diffrentiating between GET and POST request

Tags: php, post, get

The way I have PHP set up is that everything goes to a central file called Router. the router gets a parameter action and calls that method.

In Node.js, you can have get and post versions of the same method. I was wondering, is something like this possbile in PHP?

Basically I would like this to happen:

Have an add method.

Page 1 has the add button. The add button goes to the form that needs to be filled out to add an item - a get request. Upon clicking, the add method is called.

Page 2 has another add button. The add button now inserts using form data and adds an item - a post request.

Now, both call the same method, but in the file a get version of the method is defined and post version of the method is defined.

Was wondering if this is possible without having two methods with different names.

Comment: This should be done in two different methods. The reason is because a method should only do one thing. In your case, you want a method that does two.

Comment: Idk if I understood you correctly...but you COULD have one method and then differentiate what do you want to do (if request is GET or POST) and process it accordingly...

Comment: In .NET, you can give method attribuetes. So on top of the method, you can write [GET]methodName and [POST]methodName. Is there anything like this in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to determine whether it is GET or POST. A primitive attempt might look like this:

```
 function handle_request() {
   $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
   $verb = tolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
   // create string representation of the function to call, eg. post_add, get_add
   call_user_func( $verb.'_.'$action, $_REQUEST);
   }

 }
```

If you do not wish to name the function differently:

```
function add() {
  if (tolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD') == 'post') {
    // run the post version
  } else {
    // run the get version
  }
}
```

A full example implementing a REST API can be found [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest/):

Comment: But that way I would have to name the function differently. What I'm wondering is, if something like the following is possible: index.get() and index.post(), then if it's post post will be called. I realize I still have to name it differently, but this seems more elegant.

Comment: Just to understand: Is index a class?

Comment: No, it is a method. Which is why the dot is not possible. In .NET, you can give method attribuetes. So on top of the method, you can write [GET]methodName and [POST]methodName. Is there anything like this in PHP?

Comment: I don't think PHP methods have suchh functionality, though you may be interested in this SO answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947147/php-version-of-asp-net-c-property-attribute-class

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$_REQUEST`. It is universal replacement for `$_POST` or `$_GET`.